Total number of $4$ digit number formed by $0,2,3,4,6,7$

Total number of $4$ digit number in the closed interval $[2022,4482]$ formed by using the digits $0,2,3,4,6,7$,is

What I try :  ( 1 st Method :)
$\displaystyle \boxed{}\;\color{blue}{\boxed{}}\;\color{red}{\boxed{}}\;\color{purple}{\boxed{}}$
In extreme left position, We have $3$ possibilities ( either $2$ or $3$ or $4$)
$\displaystyle \bullet$ :  Fix $2$ at $1000$ th position , Then for $100$ th place we have $6$ possibilities and for $10$th place , We have $5$ possibilities and for last place , We have $5$ possibilities .
So we have $150$ ways
$\displaystyle \bullet$ :  Fix $3$ at $1000$ th position , Then for $100$ th place we have $6$ possibilities and for $10$th place , We have $6$ possibilities and for last place , We have $6$ possibilities .
So we have $216$ ways
$\displaystyle \bullet$ :  Fix $4$ at $1000$ th position , Then for $100$ th place we have $4$ possibilities and for $10$th place , We have $6$ possibilities and for last place , We have $2$ possibilities .
So we have $48$ ways
So Total $4$ digit numbers
$\displaystyle = 150+216+48=414$
But Correct Answer is $569$
$\color{blue}{\text{Second Way}}$::
(I did not understand that method)
$\displaystyle (2022)\rightarrow (1011)_{6}=223$
And $4482>4477\rightarrow (3355)_{6}=791$
So total number
$\displaystyle =791-223+1=569$
Please explain me where I have missed one first one .
And also please explain me second Method , Thanks

For 2xxx you say there are 5 possibilities for last slot. How come? This is true for 202x but not for something like 203x.

" Fix $2$ at $1000$ th position , Then for $100$ th place we have $6$ possibilities and for $10$th place , We have $5$ possibilities and for last place , We have $5$ possibilities ." You have said this with allowing $2022$ in mind. Unfortunately at the same time you have excluded one of the following six: $3000, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3006, 3007,$ even though none of those six should be excluded (i.e. they should all be included in the count). And there are many similar examples where you exclude one of six possibilities when you shouldn't have.

see here https://cms.fiitjee.com/Resources/DownloadCentre/Document_Pdf_460.pdf in question (7)

Consider the 1000-th position is $2$ and the 100-th is $0$, then the 10-th place can be filled with all 5 digits except $0$ and the unit place with all the 6 digits making a total of $30$ cases.
But we cannot have $2020$, that cancels 1 case, with a total of $29$ cases then.
After we have studied $0$, now, the 100-th place be any number except $0$, then for a total $5$ placements in this place and $6$ digits in the last two places, we have $5\times6^2=180$ cases in total for this condition.
Numbers starting with $3$ have exactly $216$ cases, as you said.
For numbers starting with $4$, the second place can contain any digits from $0,2,3,4$ and the last two places can have all the $6$ digits, making a total of $4\times6^2=144$ cases.
Thus a total of $144+29+180+216=569$ cases are found.

Numbers that contain just $0,2,3,4,6,7$ (six different digits) can be paired with base-6 numbers, that have digits $0,1,2,3,4,5$.  For example the base-10 number 2426 is paired with the base-6 number $(1314)_6$ because 2 is the second allowed decimal digit and 1 is the second base-6 digit.
The lowest number is $2022$ which is paired with $1011_6$.  The highest number with those digits is $4477$, which is paired with $3355_6$.  The allowed numbers between $2022$ and $4482$ are paired with all the base-6 numbers between $1011_6$ and $3355_6$.
$1011_6=223_{10}$ and $3355_6=791_{10}$.  The count of numbers between them is $791-223+1$

Thanks Empy2 got it . I have a doubt. what will happen for numbers $4478,4479,4480,4481,4482$ (i.e which are greater then $4477$

It is not possible to get numbers  4478-4482 because  the highest digit you are given  is 7.




This is under the assumption that repitation is allowed. You're most welcome to point my errors or a faster way of doing this. It took a while page to write as this is my 1st time explaining maths to someone so spare me, this is barely a 2 or 3 liner problem.
Thanks!
The image has my written solution

I haven’t seen your working yet, but your answer is definitely wrong. The correct answer given in the question is 569.
Also, we actually don’t like users to use image except for geometry pictures. You should type the answer out using latex , not attaching pictures.

Digit 1 in first position is not allowed.
